# Simple form transmission with react & axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a simple form rendering with reactjs and I want to pass a param from the form to complete a route to a test endpoint.

Here is the endpoint: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import MenuCombo from './menucombo'
const heading = "Enter a price cap here for recommendations"

class App extends Component {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=PriceCap')
            .then(response  =>{
                console.log("FOUND", response)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("NOT FOUND",err)
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">{heading}</h1>
                </header>
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>Enter a price</label>
                        <input  name = 'PriceCap'
                                    type = 'number'
                                    min = '1'
                                    max  ='20'/>
                        <button>Generate Suggestions</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see I cam passing the form element with the name `PriceCap` ideally the user would set this to 1 to log the data. And if it is set to any other value than 1 it logs an error. But I can't seem to get the parameter to pass properly.

I feel like this would be easier with POST but I also feel like POST is overkill given that I am only sending one param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a reference to your input by

```
<input  
    name = 'PriceCap'
    ref = {node => {this.input = node}}
    type = 'number'
    min  = '1'
    max  ='20'
/>
```

Then you can access the value in your submit handler by

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    let PriceCap = this.input.value;
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=${PriceCap}`)
        .then(...).catch(...)
}
```

Comment: `ref`? what's that property about? And is it then not relevant to use `name` anymore in react?

Comment: ref sets a reference to dom nodes. seems that there have been some changes to it with version 16.3. a description can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    val: ""
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=${this.state.val}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log("FOUND", response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("NOT FOUND", err);
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>Enter a price</label>
            <input
              name="PriceCap"
              type="number"
              min="1"
              max="20"
              onChange={e => this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
            />
            <button>Generate Suggestions</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/62xx8933pn).

Here, you store the input value in state, and then use that in your `get()` call.

Notice we added the `state`, and also an `onChange` in the `input`.